# What is a "Barn Hunt"?

Tags: dogs, training, sports

Recently I attended a "Barn Hunt" and had one of my dogs instincts tested. So what I'm curious about is if this is part of the "nose work" category of dog sports and what venues provide titles for "Barn Hunt". Is this a tracking title?

It looked like any type of breed could participate, there were what you would expect... terriers! But Great Danes also performed really well and had a lot of fun.

The rats seemed very well cared for, tame, and tolerant of being sniffed. They were kept in sturdy containers that the dogs couldn't hurt them through and the people running it were very careful to look after the rats to prevent them from being harmed.

Answer (score 1):

So I found this article about the Barn Hunt.

> For years, informal barn hunts were held in conjunction with earthdog
>   events and terrier fun days, using various rules, and as something to
>   enjoy with no pressure on handler or dog. But these informal events
>   were never a sanctioned sport. The Barn Hunt Association, LLC has
>   created a sanctioned sport honoring the traditional role of dogs in
>   ridding barns, homes, and properties of vermin. Barn Hunt opens this
>   fun sport up to any dog, of any size, type, breed or mix that can fit
>   through an 18″ wide through approximately 22″ high tunnel. In Barn
>   Hunt, you can earn titles and placements at levels from Instinct
>   through Master, and even Championships and beyond.
>
> Also for more info Barn Hunt is a fun and exciting new dog sport. In
>   Barn Hunt, dogs hunt for rats hidden in a straw bale maze. It's a
>   timed event, with levels of difficulty from Novice to Master. There
>   will be ribbons, placements, and titles. Fun tests are already being
>   held across the country and there is tremendous interest. You can find
>   out much more about the sport by going to the Barn Hunt Web Page. Barn
>   Hunt is growing rapidly in popularity. Join our facebook page and
>   yahoogroup . Look above at the Events link to find fun tests, trials,
>   training, and judge workshops; and at the club locator map to find
>   clubs in your area. We want to hear from you!
>   http://gogetfunding.com/project/barn-hunt-dog-sport-startup On this
>   webpage there is a video that you can look at.

(this answer is a repost because it was deleted by it's owner... but the info is good so I don't want it to be lost)